# Bash script to connect to wifi using xdotool hangs after invoking firefox

Tags: bash

I'm working on a bash script to connect to wifi using xdotool. It
works until the script invokes firefox.

Following error is logged after Firefox is invoked:

> /home/me/scripts/library_wifi.sh: line 8: $'\E[2K\rDevice': command not found

```
#!/bin/bash

library=$(nmcli d wifi connect Library_WiFi password XXXXXX)
ff=$(firefox)
login_button=$(xdotool mousemove 486 163 click 1)
gateway_library=$(xdotool mousemove 746 417 click 1;sleep 1; xdotool mousemove 1002 512 click 1)

$library
$ff
sleep 5
$login_button
$gateway_library
```